# Is getting the ground state of Edwards-Anderson model NP hard?

Tags: ising-model

I know 1D and 2D [Ising model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model) has a general solution. And I also know getting the ground state of 2D Ising model with transverse field and 3D Ising model is [NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard).[Onsager][Barahona]

So my question is , does the Edward-Anderson model have a general solution? or NP-hard?

Answer (score 4):

For the 2D planar Ising Edward-Anderson model, it can be solved in polynomial time. For the 3D case it is NP-hard, moreover NP-Complete.[1]

[1] Barry A. Cipra, *The Ising Model Is NP-Complete*